# Resize and Keep Controls in Thirds

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resize

Is it possible to get controls to automatically divide a space in thirds as the window resizes?  It is easy enough to do in code, but I'd like to set the parameters directly in the xaml if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Grid control. It takes up whatever space is available. You can get thirds by doing (assuming you want three columns)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinitions Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinitions Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinitions Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: +1 and a little [extra reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956832/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-a-wpf-columndefinition) around the topic.

Comment: That answered my question perfectly! Thanks.