# WPF usercontrol layout changed in production

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I build a usercontrol in our develop environment, and it looked exactly as I wanted it to look.
In our test and acceptation environment it looks exactly the same.
But, when we released it to our production environment the buttons at the bottom of the screen moved up a bit and are now slightly over a textbox.

How can I make my usercontrol so that it looks the way I want to in every environment? And what made this error possible? I believe we use the same version of Windows.

Comment: Are you using the same machine in production? could it be that you are using different windows theme?

Comment: Have you been using fixed lengths (widths, heights, margins, paddings, etc) ? If so, I'd suggest building a responsive design based on relative sizes. See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6956942/3602352](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6956942/3602352).

Comment: @Decoder94 That could be possible, can I build my usercontrol in a way it handles every theme correctly?

Comment: @AlyEl-Haddad The main grid has fixed sizes, but the columns and rows are all Height/Width = "auto" and one "*" Do you think it could be the fixed sizes of the grid that is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I usually run into this problem when I load my project onto another machine with the same windows but using a different theme to enhance performance or different screen size.

Answer (score 0):

As we couldn't find a solution, we decided to check our architecture of the form and found some ambiguities. I had made a mess of the stack panels and solved it with lots of white space. After making a proper form the problem didn't occur anymore.